# Book recommend: Start learning web design with css with basic HTML knowledge

Tags: html, css, design

I've already known some HTML, tables, link, image,...etc but just at a basic level. Now I want to learn how to build a layout for a website and design also. I want to start building a layout right a way and just learning from it, not really like reading so much theories, explanations. Many books are so verbose, they teach from the beginning of HTML or explain things too much. I don't want to waste my time. So are there any good books for me?

Answer (score 1):

To get an idea of what web design is all about, a valuable set of books is the ["А Book Apart"](http://www.abookapart.com/) series.

These are very informative and relatively current, which is not the case for many web design books. These books aren't going to teach you how to write HTML and CSS. But they will give you a great understanding of the medium "Web Design".

Alongside reading these books the best approach is to just get started creating web pages yourself and posting questions to site such as this one or [Sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out the Sitepoint website tutorials and books, as well as http://w3schools.com, especially if you're looking to get started right away. If you have some basic HTML knowledge, you may not need to read an entire book to achieve what you're trying to do.

Diving right in may be the best approach for you. You can use Firebug to look at how other sites do things. http://getfirebug.com

I hope that helps!

Comment: [I wouldn't endorse w3shools](http://w3fools.com/). Sitepoint's reference is very good though.

Comment: Hmm @John Conde didn't realize w3 was that poorly regarded. [HTML Dog](http://htmldog.com/) looks good, linked from w3fools.

Comment: I didn't know either until I saw that site. HTML dog does look very good though. Gonna have to bookmark that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Head First books to be useful and fun.  The HTML with CSS book does start with HTML but the CSS integration is included almost immediately.  Here's a link to the crazy big online store that sells books: http://amzn.to/ksDcRw

There's also a book on web design itself that is very useful stuff.  It's about how to design website for your end user, not how to implement a design with HTML/CSS: http://amzn.to/k7bXOK

I hope this helps.

-Bob

Answer (score 0):

When I learned HTML and CSS, the tutorials of designm.ag helped me very much. I used them in addition to books.

For example this one (2 Parts):

[Design a Clean Portfolio Site in Photoshop](http://designm.ag/tutorials/tutorials/clean-portfolio/) -> Shows how to make the design

[How to Code a Clean Portfolio Design](http://designm.ag/tutorials/psd-to-html-clean-folio/) -> Shows how to code this design with HTML and CSS.

Maybe these tutorials will help you to become a good website designer, too :)

Answer (score -1):

How to build web 2.0 interface
[http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/web-des...](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/web-design/web-2.0-design-style-guide.php)

How to learn basic HTML/CSS/Javascript/PHP/Etc....
http://w3schools.com/

Comment: Had to vote this down since we already mentioned w3schools isn't very good